# Function in pages of tab loaded twice

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a function in my work page that is one of the tab's page. I have written a function to be loaded once the page enters to request data from API.

Note: Other than the tabs' pages, the push open pages are working fine.

This was working fine on Ionic 3.0.1, however once I have upgraded to Ionic 3.1.0 when I enters the page the function loaded twice.

Here is my work.ts code

```
    ionViewWillEnter() {
        if(this.auth.authUser()) {
        this.isLogin = true;
        this.userData = this.auth.getUserInfo();
        } else {
        this.isLogin = false;
        }

        if(this.isLogin) {
        this.getClientList(true);
        } else {
        this.clientData = [];
        }
    }

    ...

    private getClientList(resetPage) {
        console.log('loaded getClientList');
        this.isEmpty = false;
        this.userData = this.auth.getUserInfo();
        if(resetPage) {
            this.content.scrollToTop(0);
            this.clientPage = 1;
        }
        let pageSkip = (this.clientPage-1)*this.clientPerPage;
        let postData = 'take=' + this.clientPerPage;
        postData += '&skip=' + pageSkip;
        postData += '&uid=' + this.userData.userId;
        if (this.category != '0') {
            postData += '&category=' + this.category;
        }
        if (this.gradeId) {
            postData += '&grade=' + this.gradeId;
        }

        let params = {
                link: 'app/client/my_client_list',
                data: postData,
        }
        this.showLoading('loading...');
        this.api.httpApi(params).subscribe(data => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
        if (data.status_code == 1) {
            this.clientData = [];
            if(data.data.length > 0) {
                this.clientData=data.data;
                // this.productState = 'in';
                if(this.clientPage < 1) {
                this.clientPage++;
                }

                if(data.data.length < this.clientPerPage) {
                this.isEnd = true;
                } else {
                this.isEnd = false;
                }
            } else {
                this.isEmpty = true;
                this.isEnd = false;
            }

        } else if (data.status_code == 500) {
            this.navCtrl.push('LoginPage');
        } else if (data.status_code == 0) {
            this.isEmpty = true;
            this.isEnd = false;
        } else {
            this.showError('network problem');
        }
        },
        error => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.pushLogin();
        // this.showError(error);
        });
    }
```

console log outputs

```
Hello AuthService Provider
work.ts:173  loaded getClientList
work.ts:173  loaded getClientList
```

ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.2
Xcode version: Not installed
```

***[EDIT]***

There is a work around which is put your API request function inside the constructor, then the function will only run once. But that's not solving the problem if you want to use IonViewWillEnter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently upgrading to Ionic 3.1.1 will solve this issue. If anyone else having this issue and you are still at Ionic version 3.1.0, just upgrade to 3.1.1+ will solve the problem.